# jdb annoying package name while debugging

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

I'm trying to debug my applications with jdb. I acquired a lot of things until now but I would like to polish them.

When I'm in jdb and I would like to insert a breakpoint or inspect a variable jdb needs the whole name package.class.(method/variable). Here is an example:

```
Initializing jdb ...
> 
VM Started: No frames on the current call stack

main[1] stop in com.ionsoft.engine.Engine.main
```

This is so annoying because the names that I must type are so long.

I would like to type "stop in Engine.main" like if the source and class was in the project root.

I tried to change the classpath from ./build/classes to ./build/classes/com/ionsoft/engine but if I do that the Engine.class isn't found.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.ionsoft.engine.Engine
```

Anyone have some idea?

UPDATE: In my current classpath I'm pointing to the jars not the classes.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe a little bit off topic, but why don't you use an IDE like Eclipse, Intellij, Netbeans etc.?

Comment: I prefer to use jdb because normally I'm working on environments without X and I think that installing an IDE only for the debugger is an overkill.

Comment: When you say you're "working on environments without X", you mean a server right? What about on your desktop, surely you have X or Windows or Mac OS X on there? Then you can do remote debugging from your desktop.

Comment: I appreciate the advice of using Eclipse/IDE but I used to program with vim and gdb. I debugged before with Eclipse or Netbeans but my performance is better using this kind of debuggers because they allow me to focus only in one thing. (I suppose is an old way to work).

Comment: Then I think you'll have to live with that burden. jdb stop requires a full qualified class name and there is no workaround for that (the fqn is not changeable after compilation).

Answer (score 1):

I found some useful information about this topic.

I have three options:

1. Use a .jdbrc file with something like this:

   ```
   monitor list
   stop in com.ionsoft.engine.Engine.main
   ```

   Unfortunately this is a workaround. I can set up all my breakpoints here and custom configuration.
2. Use Java Debug Interface (JDI) to program my custom "debugger".

   Useful information: [here](http://blog.headius.com/2010/07/browsing-memory-with-ruby-and-java.html)
3. Live with this burden. (as isnot2bad said)

I think I like better the second option but meanwhile I will use a combination of first and third option.